# Local Storage is not working on android lollipop cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, extjs

i have created an app in sencha touch cordova. Local storage is working fine in other version on android but when i am testing my app on android lollipop local storage is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any StackTrace or debug info to work on?

Comment: @AlperTuran i am not able to understand what are you saying.

Comment: @RajeshKumar - Alper is asking if you are getting exception?? if any, can you post it?

Comment: @Seram i am not getting any debug info. As i said local storage is working fine in lower version but not in lollipop.

Comment: See if this applies to your situation: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479767

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue and is related to a bug of the chrome engine:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479767#c61

I suggest to use websql for now that is working fine in this versione. Unfortunately there is no way to update the engine easily so if you use it you are stuck with a localstorage that clear data on every refresh like a session storage.